# Popup appears behind DialogFragment

Tags: android, popup, popupwindow, dialogfragment

I have a DialogFragment. On tapping a button in this Dialog fragment I need to display a pop up window above a particular edittext in the dialog fragment. To do this I find the absolute co-ordinates of the edittext using

```
int[] coords = {0,0};
editText.getLocationOnScreen(coords);
```

and display the popup at the required location using

```
popup.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, coords[0] + edittext.getWidth(), coords[1]);
```

But doing this displays the pop up window behind the dialog fragment. Is there any way to get the pop up above the dialog fragment?

Comment: Have you tried the `showAsDropDown()` method?

Comment: Yes I have, but I cannot use that method since showAsDropDown() method moves the pop up suitably when there is no space. But I want the pop up to be displayed at the particular position in all cases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I figured out my mistake.
The first parameter for popUp.showAtLocation should be getView() instead of popUpView.

```
popup.showAtLocation(getView(), Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, coords[0] + edittext.getWidth(), coords[1]);
```

This now draws the popup above the dialogFragment

Answer (score 2):

Show your popup on DialogFragment with **some required delay**.

Example-

new Handler().postDelayed(() -> showPopup(anchorView), 1000); // here using 1 second delay.